# Finding elements with same lastletter in a list

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I'm trying to figure out how I would use a closure which will find and groups of words that have the same ending letter.

For example: [United, Static, Rapid, Directed]
The return should be ["D":3, "c":1]

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: def answer = {list -> example .groupBy {it [1]} }.....example is a variable

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group use:

```
def list = ['United', 'Static', 'Rapid', 'Directed']

def groupped = list.groupBy{ it[ -1 ] }
assert groupped == [d:['United', 'Rapid', 'Directed'], c:['Static']]
```

For counting only you can use:

```
def counted = list.inject( [:].withDefault{ 0 } ){ res, curr ->
  res[ curr[ -1 ] ]++
  res
}
assert counted == [d:3, c:1]
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The closure would need to return the map linking letters. How would I go about this?

Comment: give an example

Comment: For example given [[United, Static, Rapid, Directed] ], the map that should be returned is ['d': 3, 'c': 1].